# How can I, and should I, load my .js files from a different file for cleanliness?

Tags: javascript, html, include, readability, code-cleanup

I have about 10 `.js` files that I am loading into `index.html` at the bottom of my `<body>` like so:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/javascript1.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/javascript2.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/javascript3.js"></script>
...
```

Is there a way to move all of my javascript includes into a separate file for improved readability?  If there is, should I do this, or are there reasons I want to keep them in the page in which they are used?

I am trying to do something along these lines, although this does not work:

At the bottom of my `<body>`:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/javascript-loader.js"></script>
```

Then in `javascript-loader.js`:

```
$.getScript("assets/js/javascript1.js");
$.getScript("assets/js/javascript2.js");
$.getScript("assets/js/javascript3.js");
...
```

Comment: I think that requirejs will do what you are wanting. Also, I'd recommend [grunt-concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$.getScript(...)` jQuery method is asynchronous, and therefore it will not retrieve your scripts consequently, resulting in the scripts being loaded in a random order (e.g. "script3" gets loaded before "script1"): so if any code in some of them relies on previous scripts there's a high chance that it may go completely wrong and fail rising some `TypeError` for undefined variables.

To make sure your scripts load in the correct order you can make synchronous Ajax calls, like this:

```
function loadScript(url) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        s = document.createElement('script');

    x.open('GET', url);
    x.send();

    s.textContent = x.responseText;
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}

loadScript("assets/js/javascript1.js");
loadScript("assets/js/javascript2.js");
// ...
```

but **this will obviously slow down your page a lot**, freezing it until all the scripts are loaded. By the way there are some good libraries (e.g. [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#intro) which relies on jQuery) to load scripts asynchronously in your page at any time, even though IMHO I wouldn't feel very good about using them.

To answer your question: if you don't want to use external libraries (with dependencies) **it's better to keep the scripts in the body of your document**: it makes them load faster and doesn't require additional effort.

Answer (score 2):

## Simple demo using jQuery:

```
var scripts = [
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js',
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js',
  'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/threejs/r76/three.js',
  'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/master/js/jquery.cloudinary.js'
];
```

#### Asynchronous loading

```
$.when( ...scripts.map(s => $.getScript(s)) )
    .done(console.log)
```

#### Consequent loading

```
$.getScript( scripts[0] )
    .then( $.getScript( scripts[1] ) )
    .then( $.getScript( scripts[2] ) )
    .then( $.getScript( scripts[3] ) )
    .then(console.log)
```

---

I've created a jQuery helper function which I usually place on the `window` object, which I called [**dependencies**](https://gist.github.com/yairEO/8b492d520e6818eab797e0b53b5bd06e) and it has `async` & `sync` methods:

#### Example:

```
window.dependencies.async({ baseDir:"/js/a/b/", files:["a.js", "b.js", "c.js"] })
```

Answer (score 1):

May be requirejs will be suitable for you.
http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html#intro

Here is example of usage of requirejs.

```
require.config({
baseUrl: 'js/lib',
paths: {
    // the left side is the module ID,
    // the right side is the path to
    // the jQuery file, relative to baseUrl.
    // Also, the path should NOT include
    // the '.js' file extension. This example
    // is using jQuery 1.9.0 located at
    // js/lib/jquery-1.9.0.js, relative to
    // the HTML page.
    jquery: 'jquery-1.9.0'
}
```

});

You have easily describe all files that need be loaded.
Also can have callback when every files is loaded.

Comment: While RequireJS is a good answer, some context (an example or just further explanation) would improve this answer significantly. Link-only answers are discouraged, since they become useless if the link goes down.

Comment: You are right. I have added example and additional description.

Answer (score 1):

There're multiple possible solutions. Some of them are:

- RequireJS (AMD)
- [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) (CommonJS)
- [ES6 Module Transpiler](https://github.com/esnext/es6-module-transpiler) (ES6 modules, will be transpiled to either AMD or CommonJS)

All of them have advantages, of course. AMD, as the name (Asynchronous Module Definition) suggests, was created for asynchronous loading.

CommonJS is largely used in Node.js environment. Browserify is used to make Node.js modules usable in browsers, too.

The ES6 Module Transpiler is based on the actual ECMAScript standard and will be supported by browsers. It supports both synchronous and asynchronous loading.

No matter how you choose, you mustn't forget that multiple HTTP requests add overhead and that multiple files should always be combined. This is possible when using one of the aforementioned, too.